# Copy Uno Analog Input Configuration To ESP32

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32, analogread

I started a project using the arduino uno and as a challenge I'm attempting to make it work with the esp32 but I've run into a roadblock. I may not describe it in proper terms, but I noticed that the analog input signal on the esp32 functions *differently* from how analog input works on the uno. After some research I found that the esp32 has a default analog width of 12, instead of the default 10 on the uno. This got me wondering what other analog settings (reference voltage, pin attenuation, width, etc.) on the esp32 are different from the uno and how I might go about getting similar results on the esp32. I found [this](https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/api/adc.html) useful page detailing some functions to mess around with the adc channels but, other than `analogSetWidth()`, I haven't been able to figure out what they do. I tried messing around with the functions mentioned in the linked page, but I ultimately made things worse.

tl;dr What analog input settings (analog width, pin attenuation, etc.) on the esp32 are different from the uno?

Comment: You've found a datasheet equivalent (or API description) for the ESP32 ADC. Find one also for the ATmega328P (Uno/Nano MCU) to compare their ADC capabilities. These are different peripherals from different manufacturers. Some features may not be present on both.

Comment: @6v6gt Your advice led me to find https://ece-classes.usc.edu/ee459/library/documents/ADC.pdf and https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/arduino-adc.html which told me exactly what I needed to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Per the advice of @6v6gt, I was able to find [this](https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/arduino-adc.html) resource and [this](https://ece-classes.usc.edu/ee459/library/documents/ADC.pdf) resource that told me the following information about the ADC configuration for the Uno's MCU (aka ATmega328P):

- The analog width defaults to 10 bits (** definitely the most important)
- The reference voltage is determined by the AVCC (power source) by default
- The ADC clock defaults to a divisor of 128 (assuming 13 ADC cycles per conversion)

Wasn't able to find anything useful about pin attenuation, though.